# Efficient way to get 2d array (kind of adjacency matrix) from 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For an array, say, `a = np.array([1,2,1,0,0,1,1,2,2,2])`, something like an adjacency "matrix" `A` needs to be created. I.e. `A` is a symmetric `(n, n)` numpy array where `n = len(a)` and `A[i,j] = 1` if `a[i] == a[j]` and `0` otherwise (`i = 0...n-1` and `j = 0...n-1`):

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
1   1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
2     1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
3       1 1 0 0 0 0 0
4         1 0 0 0 0 0
5           1 1 0 0 0
6             1 0 0 0
7               1 1 1
8                 1 1
9                   1
```

The trivial solution is

```
n = len(a)
A = np.zeros([n, n]).astype(int)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            A[i, j] = 1
        else:
            A[i, j] = 0
```

Can this be done in a `numpy` way, i.e. without loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
b = (a[:,None]==a).astype(int)
df = pd.DataFrame(b)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
2  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
5  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
6  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
7  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
8  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
9  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
```

If you want the upper triangle only, use [`numpy.tril_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html):

```
b = (a[:,None]==a).astype(float)
b[np.tril_indices_from(b, k=-1)] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(b)
```

output:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  NaN  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  NaN  NaN  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
```